# Open ItemSelectControl on a custom page (not gui extension)

Tags: tridion

I am developing a web application which will be added as a custom page in Tridion.

On the custom page I'd like to select a component of schema X. I want to use the ItemSelectControl for this purpose but I don't know how I can open that control from my custom page since I am not able to access any of Tridions javascript namespaces (e.g. $model or $const). I could simply open a new popup with the url to the ItemSelectControl and create my own filter in json but I'd rather use the constants defined in Tridions javascript namespace.

Is there a simple way to add references or something to my web application in order to access Tridions javascript namespaces? If not, do you have any suggestions how I should solve this?

More information on the custom page:

- CMS server hostname: testcms
- An empty ASP.NET project with one aspx page called Test.aspx published to path C:\TestPage\
- In IIS, a web application called TestPage in the SDL Tridion site with path to C:\TestPage\
- Trying to access the page in a broswer with url: http://testcms/TestPage/Test.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the following markup/code for your popup. (Popup page must be an .aspx page)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage" ClassName="DashboardView" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="tridion popup">
<head>
    <!-- Tridion manager -->
    <cc:TridionManager runat="server" Editor="CME">
        <dependencies runat="server">       
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</dependency>
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</dependency>
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.globalCommands</dependency>
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.Popup</dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </cc:TridionManager>
</head>
<body>
    My popup
</body>
```

This means that there is a dependency between your application and Tridion, because your popup page must inherit Tridion.Web.UI.Control.TridionPage. It's up to you if you want this. I don't know of another way to add the Tridion JavaScript files. 
(This approach is also used in the PowerTools project. Check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm afraid I've not been able to get your example markup to work. I've added a reference to Tridion.Web.UI.Core but I get an error that the tag cc can not be found. 

Are you able to get your example working without launching the page from Tridion? I am trying with http://[CMS_HOSTNAME]/[IIS_WEB_APPLICATION_NAME]/[PAGE_NAME].aspx where PAGE_NAME is the name of the aspx file with your markup example.

Comment: Add a new Editor and use this Editor as your custom page: (standard procedure for adding a new Editor)

1. Add a new virtual directory in the 'Editors' directory in IIS.
2. Add your new Editor in the System.config
3. Place your custompage (and your popup.aspx) in this new virtual directory.
4. Add a new custompage in Tridion. Point it to your new Editor. 

Add an 'empty' Editor.config to the Configuration directory of your new Editor.

Comment: Andreas: The "cc" prefix is normally defined in WebRoot\web.config. Most likely your custom page is stored in its own IIS application, which is why you get that error. So you'll need to add the prefix to its web.config or define it in-line in your page.

Comment: Peter: Thanks!

I am not able to access the Tridion namespaces no matter what I try. But thanks for the tips anyway.

I will create a GUI extension instead, those work at least :)

Comment: Creating a new Editor and using this as your custom page adds all the JavaScript namespaces to your page. (When using the <cc:Tridionmanager>)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own web application that connects to SDL Tridion (so you can use it as a Custom page or in a Custom URL for example), you should use the Core Service. This allows you to interface to the Tridion API without needing to copy (parts) of the SDL tridion Web.Config.

An example of how to use the Core Service is given on SDL Tridion World: [Item Selector Custom URL eXtension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx)

This example shows you an Item Selector build using the Core Service. Its is specifically designed to be used in a Custom URL (the link you have in Schema Fields), but can easily be converted to be used in your own web application or in a Custom Page.

Only when you are creating a SDL Tridion UI extension, you can (or should) use the Tridions javascript namespaces.